# Sitecore read a specific field under section "Data" from an Item

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore7

```
item.Fields.ReadAll();
```

Gives us all the fields of the item. Is there some way to get only the fields which are grouped under the Field Section "Data".
Just to elaborate a little more:

```
 -> Data
     - Address
     - Street
     - ZIP
 -> Extra Data
     - Phone
     - Fax
```

So in this case I want to get only the Fields defined under the section "Data".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get your template from a template ID and a database:

```
var template = TemplateManager.GetTemplate( item.Template.ID, Factory.GetDatabase("contentDatabaseName"));
```

and then

```
private static IEnumerable<TemplateField> GetDataFields(Template template)
 {
            var allFields = template.GetFields();
            var dataFields = allFields.Where(x => x.Section.Name == "Data");
            return dataFields;
}
```

now when you have the field IDs, you can get your values

```
var data = item.Fields[field.ID].Value;
```

Comment: In this way I get the fields of Template. But I want to get the Fields of an item itself and then read the values.